# Java Inner Text (getTextContents()) Problem

Tags: java, xml, regex

I'm trying to do some parsing in Java and I'm using Cobra HTML Parser to get the HTML into a DOM then I'm using XPath to get the nodes I want. When I get down to the desired level I call node.getTextContents(), but this gives me a string like

```
"\n\n\nValue\n-\nValue\n\n\n"
```

Is there a built in way to get rid of the line breaks? I would like to do a RegEx like

```
(?:\s*([^-]+)\s*-\s*([^-]+)\s*)
```

on the inner text and would really prefer not to have to deal with the possible different white space symbols in between the text.

Example Input:

```
Value
-
Value
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe (pretty sure actually) that .Net would return

    "Value - Value"

given the same input, which obviously has those line breaks inside the node. So a better way to say this, is can the DOM parser give me back that string with the irrelevant (to me at least) white spaces?

Comment: All things considered, I'm pretty slow.

You guys are right those RegExes work just fine, mine didn't - in Java that is. However Java processes RegEx it's different than .Net and JavaScript. Anyway after simplifying mine I found that `(?:\s*)([^-]+)(?:\s*)` is closest to what I want.

So my newest, and hopefully not as completely off as the last one, question is how do I get rid of the single tailing spaces that latest RegEx returns (there is one space or line break (tried with either trailing as source) after each 'Value' in the example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.replaceAll()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String trimmed = original_string.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

The first argument is a regular expression: you could replace all contiguous blocks of whitespace in the original string with `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understood the question correctly, but the simplest way to remove all the whitespace would be:

String s = node.getTextContents().replaceAll("\\s","");

If you just want to get rid of the leading/trailing whitespace, use trim().